# iOS, Camera Roll to save a photo from URL and keep the photo's exif metadata

Tags: ios, metadata, exif, camera-roll

While i am downloading a photo from URL to Camera Roll, the original exif metadata of the photo file is gone.
Is there any way to save the photo to Camera Roll and keeps all it's exif metadata?